# Spotify public search API

Tags: spotify

I use to have an app that searches artist/tracks with the Spotify API.
The request was pretty simple,
A get request with, for example, this URL -

https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?query=bob&type=artist&market=us&limit=50&offset=0

Now it seems that I need to send also a token in the header, and for getting a token I need to connect (or register) the end user to Spotify.

Did the API flow change?

I no longer can make simple public API calls for searching tracks or artists?

Also, I see in the Spotify docs that the Authorization Required if market=from_token is supplied in the query string.
Otherwise, optional.

Answer (score 4):

I know its too late to answer this question.
Yes, you need to get access_token and pass it with your search url to get result. Try to get Spotify access_token as follows,

```
func callToken() {
        let parameters = ["client_id" : "your client id",// u get in developer account in Spotify.
                          "client_secret" : "ur secret id",
                          "grant_type" : "client_credentials"]
        Alamofire.request("https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token", method: .post, parameters: parameters).responseJSON(completionHandler: {
            response in
            print(response)
            print(response.result)
            print(response.result.value)
            if let result = response.result.value {
                let jsonData = result as! NSDictionary
                let token = jsonData.value(forKey: "access_token") as? String
                print(token!)
              }
    })
    }
```

Then save that token and call in ur search url like

```
search url = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=Linkin+Park&type=track&limit=5&access_token=\(token)"    // pass the token in this string thats it..
```

Just go through online tutorial in youtube :- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KLsP7oThgHU&t=1s for latest version in 2019.

Download full source code with Spotify Integration + search options + default Spotify url and fetch current user's playlist and play in our native iOS App Source:- https://github.com/azeemohd786/Spotify-Demo

Answer (score 3):

All requests to the Spotify API must provide an access token. Tokens don't need to be attached to users though, you can use the [Client Credentials Flow](https://beta.developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/#client-credentials-flow) to generate an access token on behalf of your oauth client, rather than involving a user.

Can you let me know where you saw the Authorization Header marked as optional? I'd like to fix that.

Best,

Hugh

Spotify Developer Support

Comment: Hey,
saw it on the search docs
https://beta.developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/search/search/

Comment: Docs still suggest an access token isn't required for certain actions: "To access private data through the Web API, such as user profiles and playlists, an application must get the user’s permission to access the data." https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/

Comment: I don't agree that that sentence implies that an access token isn't required. It's saying to access private (i.e. a *user's*) data, you'll need their permission (in the form of a user token) - whereas to access public data (song metadata for example) you can use an app access token without a user permission. Compare the authorization code oauth flow to the client credentials oauth flow and you'll see the distinction.

Answer (score 0):

firstly you need to get your client_id and client secret in order to access your token.
using this code,

```
token_url = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token'
message = f"{Client_ID}:{Client_secret}"
messagebase64 = base64.b64encode(message.encode())
data={
    "grant_type": "client_credentials",
}
token_header={
    "Authorization": f"Basic {messagebase64.decode()}"
}

r = requests.post(token_url, data=data, headers=token_header)
token = r.json()
```

Using this code you will get a Spotify access token in return.
Then you could search a playlist or whatever using the token.

```
spotify_token = token['access_token']
information = requests.get(url=f"https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=Linkin+Park&type=track&limit=5&access_token={spotify_token}")

print(information.json())
```

Please check out this link [Spotify API documentation](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/#/operations/search)